# Как решить проблему с preg_split()?

Tags: php

есть такая строка

```
var_dump($string)

string(125) "<div style="position: relative"><a href="/lists/m_act%5Bcountry%5D/1/">США</a></div>"
```

пытаюсь исключить
 `<div style="position: relative"><a href="/lists/m_act%5Bcountry%5D/1/"></a></div>` 
пока только беру первую часть вот так

```
$regOne='/<div (.*)="(.*)"><a href="(.*)/\d/">/';
$repl="";
var_dump(preg_split($regOne,$repl,(string)$string));
```

получаю preg_split() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given

Comment: Функция `preg_split` делает не то что вам требуется http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php Используйте `preg_replace` для замены.

Comment: Вам ни один из ответов не подошел?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Исключить - просто выкинуть за ненадобностью? Есть нативная функция[`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Если данные из регулярки нужно достать - то используйте `preg_match` или `preg_match_all`

Comment: Ага тут строка html какая вам тут регулярка, строите dom дерево и получаете всё что нужно...

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = '<div style="position: relative"><a href="/lists/m_act%5Bcountry%5D/1/">США</a></div>';
$htmlDOM = new DOMDocument();
$htmlDOM->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($htmlDOM);
echo $val = $xpath->query('//div/a')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```